# Variable name substitution undefined in cloud build gcp

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cicd, google-cloud-build, cloudbuild.yaml

Hi all I have an issue which I am unable to proceed. According to the user guide, it mentioned that $REPO_NAME is supposed to be substitute to the repository name checked out.

An example the repository that is being check out is **DEMO**

I would like to create in the workspace a folder name DEMO.

When I use the code snippet below it will output as

```
— workspace
  — $REPO_NAME

my expectations is

- workspace
  - DEMO
```

```
steps:
- name: 'ubuntu'
  id: 'prerequisite'
  script: |
    #!/usr/bin/env bash
    mkdir /tmp/$REPO_NAME
    mv -v * /tmp/$REPO_NAME/
    cp -r /tmp/$REPO_NAME /workspace/
    ls -ltr
```

is there a way that I can use these variable throughout?

Comment: can you try this and see if it works   `cp -r /tmp/${REPO\_NAME} /workspace/${REPO\_NAME}`

Comment: can you check this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71361387/gcp-cloud-build-what-is-repo-name-variable) which might help

Comment: @SathiAiswarya I have already check on that and it’s not working. It is working for the docker build. Not for script. You can try on your gcp and let me know if it work. Maybe we have different version.

Comment: try adding this `export REPO_NAME=DEMO`  as mentioned [here](https://gist.github.com/pydevops/cffbd3c694d599c6ca18342d3625af97#:~:text=IMAGE_NAME%3D%22hello%2Dapp%22-,export%20REPO_NAME%3Dteam1,-export%20TAG_NAME%3D%22tag1)

Answer (score 0):

Per https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/configuring-builds/substitute-variable-values#mapping_substitutions_to_environment_variables

> Scripts don't directly support substitutions, but they support environment variables. You can map substitutions to environment variables, either automatically all at once, or manually by defining every environment variable yourself.

Have you set `automapSubstitutions`?

Comment: I tried to substitute it via the declared variables _REPO: $REPO_URL. Yet it print out to be the same